# jquery animate coincide with height toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, jquery-masonry

Essentially I have a container with a lot of content with absolute positioning. I have a height toggle that increases the height of one on `mouseenter`, and goes back to normal on `mouseleave`. Here is the jquery:

```
function newHeightSlide(sel1,sel2){
    $(sel1).mouseenter(function(){
        $(sel2,this).animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        },'normal');
    });
    $(sel1).mouseleave(function(){
        $(sel2,this).animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        },'normal');
    });
}
```

The issue is that due to the change in height with the absolute positioning, elements can overlap

I am using [Jquery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) in order to create the absolute positioning. So I tried adding a callback function in the [completion part of .animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete), but that will only execute the function **after** the animation is complete

I need to call this function during the animation so that as the height increases to one element, the elements below it move down even though they have absolute positioning

**I already have the function I need. I just need to be able to call it so that it coincides with the toggling animation so that it runs multiple times and creates an animating effect that flows with the `height:"toggle"`**

## Extra Info

in case it is important, here is the callback function:

```
$('#posts').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.post, .post_photo',
    isAnimated: false
});
```

**note:** isAnimated is set to false because when it is true, although it eases the transition, it causes other features to move while it configures and looks very messy. This should not make a difference if I could get this function to run as the `toggle` height runs, this way it will look like easing anyways because it will ease the way it would if I was simply animating the height

Comment: Do you know about `z-index`? Any reason why you wouldn't want to use that?

Comment: and how would z-index move down the other content to prevent overlap?

Comment: It doesn't, it can bring elements to the front so you don't need to implement bumping. If you do want bumping, please ignore my comment.

Comment: Can you transform your elements to be relative positionned instead of absolute ? So you could put them all in the same stacking context and they won't overlap each other, the container would adapt its height to its content.

Comment: I am using [Jquery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Which changes all elements to absolute so that it can fit them together like bricks. And I need the bump, I can increase the stack with z-index, but then it overlaps in a sloppy way